# Pass value of application item to SQL query in list of value

Tags: oracle-apex, lov

I'm working with Oracle APEX 23.1. I want to create a list of value (LOV_item1) based on value of an application item (APP_item1).
APP_item1 has a corresponding application computation which is calculated before header.
Apparently, SQL query in LOV_item1 cannot read value of APP_item1, hence no value is shown when I use LOV_item1 in page 1.

Do I miss something when implementing APP_item1?

Comment: How did you reference application item? Should be something like `where some_col = :APP_ITEM1`. Also, did you try to put APP_ITEM1 into "Parent Item(s)" property?

Comment: When asking questions it is always helpful to explain in detail what you're doing. The sample emp/dept dataset (APEX > SQL Workshop > utilities > sample datasets > EMP/DEPT) is a good start. If you explain the issue using that dataset it is a lot easier to understand and reproduce for everyone.

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes I used exactly the same code `select column1 from table1 where column2=:APP_item1`. Then I assigned LOV_item1 to a page item PAGE_item1. When running application, I clicked in this item PAGE_item1 and search for the first two letter, but there is no result returned from LOV. The APP_item1 is actually an application item, so it was defined in shared component. I'm not sure how to set its "Parent item(s)" in this case?

Comment: It turns out that I used the wrong name of appl_item1 in SQL query of lov_item1. Thanks for your supporting.